# Disabling the purchase for one product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to turn off the possibility of buying a selected product, but all the materials I have found so far do not work for me. I would like to exclude a specific product, preferably by removing the button, because I want this product to work like any other, but without the possibility to be buying.

This code would be perfect for me:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable');
function filter_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    return ( $product->id == 534 ? false : $is_purchasable );
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're not trying to apply it on a VARIABLE product, your code should work @Loic.
Are you trying it on a Simple or a Variable product? If it's a Variable product, then take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code should be different **depending on the product type** (variable or not).
Take a look below at what I used for both types:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'change_products_purchaseable_state', 23, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'change_products_purchaseable_state', 23, 2 );

function change_products_purchaseable_state( $is_purchasable, $product ) {

    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    // For product variations (from variable products)
    if ( $product->is_type('variation') ){
        $parent = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() );
        $product_id = $parent->get_id();
    } 

    // Check if the Product belongs to a specific Category
    if( has_term( 51, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

**This code should work for all places: Single Product Page, Shop Page and other places where you use a WooCommerce Template or Shortcode.**

Answer (score -1):

This code is just a bit outdated since Woocommerce 3, as `$product->id` need to be replaced with `$product->get_id()`… Try the following instead *(where 534 is the related product ID where add to cart button will not appear)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'purchasable_product_customizations', 10, 2 );
function purchasable_product_customizations( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    if( in_array( $product->get_id() == 534 )
        $is_purchasable = false;

    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### If your product ID is a variable product

For a variable product ID where you want to disable allvariations, you will replace this line:

```
if( in_array( $product->get_id() == 534 )
```

by this one:

```
if( in_array( $product->get_parent_id() == 534 )
```

> If it still doesn't work is that something else is interacting and making trouble, like some customizations made by you, your theme or a plugin… Also it can be because you are not adding this code in the right place.

Comment: All modifications add a child theme to the functions.php, unfortunately in this case it receives the HTTP ERROR 500, and the page stops working.

Comment: There are closing brackets missing after the ```if```s